# .uid: The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'. - Flutter, FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, uid

My .uid says: The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.

My Code:

```
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
 
 class AuthService {   final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth =
 FirebaseAuth.instance;
 
   Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
 _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(
         (User user) => user?.uid,
       );
 
   Future<String>
 createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       String email, String password, String name) async {
     final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: email,
       password: password,
     );
 
     var updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName:name);
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload();
     return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;   }
 
 Future<String>
 signInWithEmailAndPassword(
       String email, String password) async {
     return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
             email: email, password: password))
         .uid;   }
 
   signOut() {
     return _firebaseAuth.signOut();   } }
 
 class UserUpdateInfo { }
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` methods return a [`UserCredential` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html), which (as the error message says) doesn't have a `uid` property. To get to the UID from the `UserCredential`, you do `credential.user.uid`.

You're looking for:

```
await (_firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user.uid
```

Or a bit more readable when spread over two lines/statements:

```
var credentials = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
return credentials.user.uid
```